# $scope variable not ready - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a initialise function that perform certain actions on `$scope.vacancylist`. The problem I am having is `$scope.vacancylist` does gets populated after my init functions gets executed. I did some research and apparently I need to use watch on this scope variable, Can someone help me out on this as I am still in the learning phase.

```
    $scope.Init = function () {

    // $scope.vacancylist <-- do certain actions once its been populated


    }
```

Comment: Do you use a controller and use angular dependency injection for the $scope variable?

Comment: yes i am using it.

Comment: you can use `$scope.$watch`

Comment: Do I need to wrap the whole function around it?

Comment: you mean the `$scope.vacancylist` gets populated but you can't see its content?

Comment: No! $scope.vacancylist does gets populated but after the Init function gets executed. I want to add some sort of $watch on that scope property so once it gets populated I will be able to perform certain actions using it.

Answer (score 0):

Worked out, it should be like:

```
    $scope.$watch('vacancylist', function () {

    if (($routeParams.vacancy != null) && ($scope.vacancylist.length > 0)) {
        var single_object = $filter('filter')($scope.vacancylist, function (d) { return d.VacancyId == $routeParams.vacancy; })[0];
        $scope.Vacancy = single_object;
    }
});
```